# What is the url for AWS SDK v3 for esm?

Tags: aws-sdk, es6-modules, supabase, deno

Hi I am coding a supabase edge function.

What I am trying to do is send email with AWS SES service.

In order to do that I need to import AWS SDK v3 into the edge function.

Now as we know supabase edge functions dont allow to install packages. So we have to import packages by using import maps.

Does anyone knows what is the import map url for AWS SDK v3? using esm.sh or any other cdn?

my current import_map file looks like this:

```
{
    "imports": {
        "stripe" : "https://esm.sh/stripe@latest?target=deno",
        "aws-sdk" : "https://esm.sh/@aws-sdk@latest?target=deno"
    }
}
```

But obviously it is not working.

Comment: `@aws-sdk` isn't a package, that's just a namespace. `@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb`, for example, is a package. There isn't one singular package; it's modular, you bring in the pieces you need. [Reading their docs would be a good start](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/modular-packages-in-aws-sdk-for-javascript/)

Comment: ok, but how do I get it on a deno server. Because it does not allow you to install any packages. You need a CDN url to require it.

Comment: You'd use it just as you're doing above. To be clear, the issue is that you're trying to import something that doesn't (and can't) exist, not that your method of importing is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to import individual AWS packages, e.g.

```
{
  "imports": {
    "aws/s3": "https://esm.sh/@aws-sdk/client-s3@3.485.0",
    "aws/dynamodb": "https://esm.sh/@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb@3.485.0",
  }
}
```